# vb.net If Else statement

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have this if else statement that I need help with.
What I would like to happen is the user enters a number in data grid view columnIndex 0. If the first validation (If CheckSatus(chkValue)) fails turn the back color red and stop. If its valid I want to continue to CheckRelease(chkValue). Right now if its invalid it goes to CheckRelease(chkValue) and change the back color yellow.

Current Code:

```
 Private Sub gridUserEntries_CellLeave(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles gridUserEntries.CellLeave
        'Validate Release Number is validate and that Release is in F4 screen

        If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
            Dim currCell As DataGridViewCell = gridUserEntries.CurrentCell
            Dim chkValue As String = currCell.GetEditedFormattedValue(currCell.RowIndex, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display)

            If Not (chkValue.Trim = "") Then
                'Validate if release is in jobscopedb.IPJOBM table
                If CheckSatus(chkValue) Then
                    currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
                Else
                    currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
                    btnUpdatePPUSRFS.Enabled = False
                    btnClear.Enabled = True
                End If
                'Validate if the Release Number is in the PPUSRFS TABLE
                If CheckRelease(chkValue) Then
                    currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
                    btnValidate.Enabled = True
                    btnRetrieve.Enabled = True
                    btnClear.Enabled = True
                Else
                    currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
                    btnInsertPPUSRFS.Enabled = True
                    btnValidate.Enabled = False
                    btnRetrieve.Enabled = False
                End If

            Else
                currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
            End If

        End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify each test by only looking for the failure condition (no `Else` block), and then use a `Return` statement to stop processing. Then put the success code just once, after all the tests:

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
    Dim currCell As DataGridViewCell = gridUserEntries.CurrentCell
    Dim chkValue As String = currCell.GetEditedFormattedValue(currCell.RowIndex, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display)

    'Validate if release is in jobscopedb.IPJOBM table
    If String.IsNullOrWhitespace(chkValue) Then     
        currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red
        btnUpdatePPUSRFS.Enabled = False
        btnClear.Enabled = True
        Return ' or Exit Sub
    End If

    'Validate if the Release Number is in the PPUSRFS TABLE
    If Not CheckRelease(chkValue) Then
        currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        btnInsertPPUSRFS.Enabled = True
        btnValidate.Enabled = False
        btnRetrieve.Enabled = False
        Return
    End If

    ' Add as many other tests as you need

    'Made it this far means success
    currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
    btnValidate.Enabled = True
    btnRetrieve.Enabled = True
    btnClear.Enabled = True
End If
```

Even better, use a boolean so you also only need the failure code once:

```
If (e.ColumnIndex = 0) Then
    Dim currCell As DataGridViewCell = gridUserEntries.CurrentCell
    Dim chkValue As String = currCell.GetEditedFormattedValue(currCell.RowIndex, DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Display)

    'Validate if release is in jobscopedb.IPJOBM table
    Dim Success As Boolean = Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(chkValue)

    'Validate if the Release Number is in the PPUSRFS TABLE
    Success = Success AndAlso CheckRelease(chkValue)


    ' Add as many other tests as you need

    If Success Then
        currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
        btnValidate.Enabled = True
        btnRetrieve.Enabled = True
        btnClear.Enabled = True
    Else
        currCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow
        btnInsertPPUSRFS.Enabled = True
        btnValidate.Enabled = False
        btnRetrieve.Enabled = False
    End If
End If
```

Note the use of `AndAlso`, which short-circuits, meaning it will stop evaluating the expression as soon as it knows that logical result (when the first part is `False`). The `CheckRelease()` only runs if `Success` is `True`. We can use this to further reduce the code:

```
Dim Success As Boolean = 
    Not String.IsNullOrWhitespace(chkValue) AndAlso
    CheckRelease(chkValue) AndAlso
    SomeOtherTest() AndAlso
    AsManyAsYouNeed()
```